# ffmpeg -headers Command how to allow certain domain name

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, headers, iptv, cors

I'm working on XUI ONE server , XUI Panel has the option to set default http header using ffmpeg headers command.
I have searched on google unfortunately there are very few documents on ffmpeg headers command information.

So I want to restrict stream request to allow only certain domain name, I have applied the below code but it's not working , my main purpose is to allow only my website to access the URL streams and block all other requests.

```
ffmpeg -headers "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true" -headers Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, HEAD" -headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.net'
```

Can any ffmpeg experts can help me out?

[image]